# Perl script to pair two array

Tags: perl

I want to pair two array and add char '/' between them. Let say, two arrays are like below

```
@array1 = (FileA .. FileZ);
@array2 = (FileA.txt .. FileZ.txt);
```

The output that I want is like below

```
../../../experiment/fileA/fileA.txt
.
.
../../../experiment/fileZ/fileZ.txt
```

here is my code

```
my @input_name = input();
my $dirname = "../../../experiment/";

# CREATE FOLDER PATH
my @fileDir;
   foreach my $input_name (@input_name){
   chomp $input_name;
   $_ = $dirname . $input_name;
   push @fileDir, $_;
  }

# CREATE FILE NAME
my @filename;
my $extension = '.txt';
foreach my $input_name (@input_name){
      chomp $input_name;
   $_ = $input_name . $extension;
   push @filename, $_;
}
```

The code that I'd try is like below. But it seem doesn't work

```
#CREATE FULL PATH
foreach my $test_path (@test_path){
    foreach my $testname (@testname){
       my $test = map "$test_path[$_]/$testname[$_]", 0..$#test_path;
       push @file, $test;
   }
}


print @file;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `input()` returns something like `('fileA', 'fileB')`.

The problem with your code is the nested loop here:

```
foreach my $test_path (@test_path){
    foreach my $testname (@testname){
```

This combines every `$test_path` with every possible `$testname`. You don't want that. Also, it doesn't make much sense to assign the result of `map` to a scalar: All you'll get is the number of elements in the list created by `map`.

(Also, you have random `chomp` calls sprinkled throughout your code. None of those should be there.)

You only need a single array and a single loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub input {
    return ('fileA', 'fileB');
}

my @input = input();
my $dirname = '../../../experiment';

my @files = map "$dirname/$_/$_.txt", @input;

for my $file (@files) {
    print "got $file\n";
}
```

Here the loop is hidden in the `map ..., @input` call. If you want to write it as a `for` loop, it would look like this:

```
my @files;
for my $input (@input) {
    push @files, "$dirname/$input/$input.txt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your algorithm. You're iterating all filenames and all dirnames at the same time.
I mean, your code says "For every directory, create every file".

Try something along the lines of this and you'll be fine:

```perl
# WRITE TESTFILE
    foreach my $filename (@filename){
        chomp $filename;
        if ( -e "$filename/$filename" and -d "$filename/$filename" ){
            print "File already exists\n";
        }
        else {
            open ( TXT_FILE, ">$filename/$filename" );

            print TXT_FILE "Hello World";

            close TXT_FILE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion. The problem is on the second array, i want it have file extension.